# C++ linker warning because of virtual destructor / clang

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, clang++, llvm-clang

I'm getting a linker warning caused by virtual destructors. My environment is the KEIL compiler v6.5 (clang).

```
Warning: L6439W: Multiply defined Global Symbol __clang_call_terminate defined in invalid_group(new.cpp.o) rejected in favor of Symbol defined in .text.__clang_call_terminate(cxa_handlers.cpp.o).
```

I get this warning as soon as I add the virtual destructor to an interface. For example:

```
class IInterface {
  virtual ~IInterface(){}

  virtual void doSomething() const = 0;
}
```

As soon as I implement one single derived class of this interface I get the above mentioned warning. As soon as I remove the virtual destructor, the warning vanishes.

I tried really many things to find out what's the reason, but didn't succeed...

Does someone know how to fix this warning?

Thank you!

Edit: A complete example throwing this warning:

```
class IInterface {
  public:
  virtual ~IInterface();

  virtual void doSomething() = 0;
};

IInterface::~IInterface() {

}

class SomeClass : public IInterface {
  public:
  virtual void doSomething();
};

void SomeClass::doSomething() {

}

int main() {

}
```

Comment: Can you try `virtual ~IInterface() = default;` instead?

Comment: Do you provide an implementation of the destructor in both base and derived classes? A pure virtual destructor needs an implementation, despite being pure virtual.

Comment: @n.m. It looks it's implemented in the base class, and the derived one will use the default dtor if there's no user-provided one.

Comment: @vsoftco didn't fix the issue.

Comment: @n.m. I've tried all possible combinations of destructor implementations. Unluckyly neither of them fixed the issue.

Comment: That error often comes up when you have something in a header file but don't wrap it in a header guard.  Interesting that you're managing to get it just from your complete sample, presumably all just in one *.cpp file.

Comment: @Mitch: exactly, that is the big question now. (If the header guard is broken, you'd have multiple definitions of the destructor (inadvertently) because the interface contains an inline implementation of the destructor.)

Comment: @Andreas did you double check your header guards? What happens if you use `virtual ~IInterface() = 0;` instead of `virtual ~IInterface() {}` ?

Answer (score 3):

I asked support of ARM and got the information that this warning is spurious. So it seems to be an issue of the current ARM clang compiler toolchain implementation.

Nevertheless thank you all for your responses on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

If you define your function in header you will emit the function each time you include it in a file. To remove this warming you need to define your method outside the declaration

```
// IInterface.hpp
class IInterface {
public:
  virtual ~IInterface();
}

// IInterface.cpp
IInterface::~IInterface() {}
```

Comment: Actually if the definition is inside the class (as in the top snippet) it's inlined, so it should work fine (assuming of course proper include guards).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this was a linker bug which has been fixed in ARM Compiler v6.11 (10/25/2018).

Release notes:

> [SDCOMP-30157]  In certain circumstances, after discarding a section from a COMDAT ELF section group, the linker could incorrectly report Warning: L6439W: Multiply defined Global Symbol  defined in invalid_group() rejected in favour of Symbol defined in (). This has been fixed.